# jQuery how to combine this and a variable

Tags: jquery, this, selector

I have a form where the ID changes depending on the page.

I am trying to get the value of the input name `email` but am using `$(this)` to make sure I don't conflict with any other forms that may be on the same page.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#layers-widget-form_builder-27 .builderForm').each(function() {
        $(this).on("submit", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var formData = $(this).serialize();
            var emailId ='sam.skirrow@gmail.com';
            var emailSubject ='New website form submission';
            var mcListID ='9069741672';
            var mcAPIkey ='d87ebb1e2bf13d4624009f2f5ea9a9aa-us12';
            var mcEmail = $(this + 'input[name="email"]').val(); 
            var mcLname ='last_name';
            var mcFname ='first_name';
            var mcForm = $(this);

            ...

        });
    });
});
```

To create a var for email I am using

```
var mcEmail = $(this + 'input[name="email"]').val();
```

but this is throwing up syntax errors - what is the correct way of combining $this with a selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method to find  the descendants within an element.

```
var mcEmail = $(this).find('input[name="email"]').val();
```

Comment: And alternatively, `$('input[name="email"]',this)`. See [selector context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context).

Comment: Additional clarification: In this case, "this" is the <form> DOM node itself. By saying this + '.selector', you are appending a string to an object, and then trying to wrap it in jQuery - which makes no sense. As the solution shows, you create a jQuery object out of the form, and then call the `find()` method to find specific descendant(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selector` like

```
$('my_selector p').click(function(){
    var selector = $(this).selector;
    var combined = $(selector + '[name=email]');
    alert( combined.val() );
})
```